# Is the error budget in GCP UI supposed to rise above 100%?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, sli, sre

I have just started using SLO's in GCP and my first SLI seems to be working, but, the "error budget" field is way above 100%. All the examples I have seen online sit at 100%, whereas mine seems to float between 700.00% and above in to the thousands. Has anyone else experienced this?

My SLI is configured via Terraform as a "request_based_api" and I am using a "good_total_ratio" query where I provide the "good_service_filter" and "totaL_service_filter"s that are the custom log metrics that are reporting log entries based on textPayload of a custom log. My service begins as a function which creates a log entry that represents the beginning request (hence gets picked up by the total_service_filter), and the service ends as a Cloud Build process that also writes a log entry to the same log representing a successful completion (hence gets picked up by good_service_filter).

As I said, it appears to be working, but with the error budget being so high, I am not sure. I haven't been able to find any examples that show it as anything other than 100% which is making me question whether I have messed it up somehow.

Comment: Error budget should not exceed 100 if the computation has been set correctly, You can check the [Art of SLO](https://sre.google/resources/practices-and-processes/art-of-slos/) from the official website of Google SRE.

Comment: thanks @AlexG . I'll go back and re-check the underlying data feeding my SLI.